# MemoryMappedFile Process Security

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files, inter-process-communicat, security-identifier

I'm trying to create a MemoryMappedFile and ensure that only certain processes have access to the shared memory. This [blog post on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4.aspx) says:

> The memory mapped file security allows you to customize who or ***which process*** can have access to the resource, this can be quite important when you want to protect sensitive information and you don’t want other processes changing the file map.

However, I cannot figure out how to reference a process, only the built-in SIDs which reference users and user groups. This works, but is not what I'm looking for:

```
MemoryMappedFileSecurity mmfs = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();
SecurityIdentifier si = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.LocalServiceSid, null);
AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights> ar = new AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>(si, MemoryMappedFileRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow);
mmfs.AddAccessRule(ar);
MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("testmmf", 134217728, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite, MemoryMappedFileOptions.None, mmfs, System.IO.HandleInheritability.None);
```

How do I reference my processes? Does my process have an SID? What concept am I completely missing?

Comment: Processes do not have SIDs, but the owner of a process does.  The process itself is identified by the PID. SIDs are linked to Window's Security Principles.

Comment: If that's the case, how do I reference a PID in the MemoryMappedFileSecurity object? Can't find anywhere that I'd be able to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, that part I do not know. I'm not quite sure that you can.